# manipulate a column of dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

`enter code here`In order to change strings' suffix to be prefix  in a column of dataframe, which is made with the following code for example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['100000.ss','200000.zz'],'b':[10,18]},index=[1,2])


      a         b
1   100000.ss   10
2   200000.zz   18
```

I tried one line code below, but the result shows the if else statement doesn't work. Why?

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'ss.'+x[:6] if x.find("ss") else 'zz.'+x[:6])


      a         b
1   ss.100000   10
2   ss.200000   18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `x` of your lambda function is a string. `x.find` returns `-1` if not found. `-1` is considered as boolean `True`. Therefore, your lambda always returns `ss + ...`. Try to change your lambda to this

```
df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'ss.'+x[:6] if x.find("ss") != -1 else 'zz.'+x[:6])

Out[4]:
1    ss.100000
2    zz.200000
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

Anyway, you don't need `apply` for this issue. Just use pandas `str` accessor

```
df['a'].str[-2:] + '.' + df['a'].str[:-3]

Out[10]:
1    ss.100000
2    zz.200000
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just realized .find() actually returns an integer pointing to the first character of the string it find.

Comment: you are welcome. yes, it returns the index of the first char of the found substring or `-1` on not found.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the hardwork when there is a library that does it for you....

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['100000.ss','200000.zz'],'b':[10,18]},index=[1,2])
df.assign(
    a=lambda x: x["a"].apply(lambda s: f"{Path(s).suffix[1:]}.{Path(s).stem}")
)
```

**output**

```
         a   b
 ss.100000  10
 zz.200000  18
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be options to this in a lower number of lines. I have a solution

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['100000.ss','200000.zz'],'b':[10,18]},index=[1,2])
    df[['First','Last']] = df.a.str.split(".",expand=True)
    df['a']=df['Last']+'.'+df['First']
    df.drop(['First','Last'],axis=1)
```